Is the condition $f(x)=f(-x)$ equivalent to spherical symmetry?
Let $f\colon\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ be a function of three dimensions.
We say $f$ is spherically symmetric if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ for all $|x_1|=|x_2|.$
Suppose now that $f$ satisfies the condition $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$. Is this condition equivalent to spherical symmetry?

No. For example, think of a cube centered around origin. It has inversion symmetry, but not spherical symmetry.

No. Let $f(x,y,z)=|x|$. Then $f(-x,-y,-z)=|-x|=|x|=f(x,y,z)$, but $f(1,0,0) =1 \neq 0 =f(0,1,0)$, while $\|(1,0,0)\|=\|(0,1,0)\|=1$.
